# Is static pages controller required for every static page?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails app and was wondering if a controller function is required for every static page even if it just contains HTML and CSS? I know I have to create a view and change routes.rb, but why do you have to define a controller function for each page?

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

So here do I need to define "about" even if it is just static content?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not required. If the method that `routes` maps to is not defined in the controller specified *and* there is no view file with that name, then you'll get an error that the method is not defined in the controller. But if the view is present and the method is not, it will go ahead and accept it as if the method was defined.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I also read that it is required but it seems to work for me without it. At least manually typing in the site name works without a problem. Is that still supposed to work? @Peter Alfvin

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that. Just updated answer to reflect the feedback and testing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem if you don't want to define those empty actions